# Join a table to itself to display average value?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of game scores for various teams and various years.

Database looks like this:

```
id |team|year|week|points
1 | Wildcats|2015|1|43
2 | Wildcats|2015|2|50
```

I want to create a display that shows each team in the database, its total points scored for the year, and the league average points for that year.

So it might look like:

```
Wildcats 2015  387  44.3
```

etc.

I was trying this, but it's not working:

```
SELECT g1.year, g1.team, xyz.total 
FROM game g1
join (SELECT avg(points) as total, year
            FROM game g2) xyz on g1.year=xyz.year
group by g1.year, g1.team
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to get average points per year:

```
SELECT team, year, SUM(points) AS totalPoints,  
       (SELECT AVG(points)
        FROM game AS g2
        WHERE g2.year = g1.year) AS avgPoints
FROM game AS g1
GROUP BY team, year
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4832a/2)

or, with joining a derived table:

```
SELECT g1.team, g1.year, SUM(g1.points) AS totalPoints,  
       g2.avgPoints
FROM game AS g1
JOIN (SELECT AVG(points) AS avgPoints, year
      FROM game
      GROUP BY year
) AS g2 ON g1.year = g2.year
GROUP BY team, year
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4832a/3)

Comment: The first one worked.  I was close in my attempt.  I didn't try the second method.  Is there an advantage to using one or the other?

Comment: @RichieW13 The first query uses a correlated subquery, whereas the second an innner join. There is no golden as to which method is the most efficient. You should try both with your actual data and see which one performs better.

Answer (score 0):

May this query is what you looking for:

```
select team,year,sum(points)as total,cast(avg(points)as decimal(10,1))  
  as average from your_table_name group by team,year
```

Comment: This one didn't do what I was hoping for.  This one gives me the average for each team for the year.  I was looking for the league average for each year.  Giorgos' solution worked.  Thanks.